# How to kill an idle process within a for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I looked for a solution on many forums but I didn't find any suitable ones...

I have several functions (let's say file_1.req file_2.req...file_100.req) I would like to launch with the associated program (let's say calculate.exe). A normal calculation is done within approx. 10s. For some reasons, a file_i.req may make calculate.exe get stuck and the following functions (from i+1 to n) won't be launched (idle case). To avoid this problem, I want to write a batch file which would call calculate.exe for each file_i.req and which would use a 'timeout' (let's say 15s) to perform calculations in a finite time. Moreover it would continue with a 'taskkill' for file_i.req in case 'timeout' elapsed (without waiting for user's commands). I would like my script to continue with the 'i+1' .req file's calculation. 
I can not use 'start' for calculate.exe which would open n windows for each req file.
Here is my pseudo-code in the .bat file :

```
set enabledelayedexpansion
set beginning=file_
set extension=.req

for /L %%g in (1,1,100) do(
     set file_req=%beginning%%%g%extension%
     call calculate.exe -f %file_req%
     :: timeout /T 15 /nobreak
     :: taskkill (calculate.exe -f %file_req%)
     :: continue
)
endlocal
```

Thanks a lot for helping !

Pierre

Comment: *Hello world^^ (excuse me...)

Comment: You don't use `call` with an `.exe` file, and if you were able to delete an executable command, as opposed to an executable file, like that, _which you cannot_, you'd need to account for setting and using a variable within the same code block.

Comment: The variables and delayed expansion are not required when using a for /L loop in this context.  Use the loop variable to increment the file. `file_%%g.req`

Comment: Do not use `::`-style comments i code blocks, they cause unexpected behavior! Use [`rem`](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) instead...

Comment: Alright, thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" == "/watch" goto :watcher

set "beginning=file_"
set "extension=.req"
set "executable=calculate.exe"
set "max_seconds=15"

for /l %%A in (1,1,100) do (
    start "" /b cmd /s /d /c ^""%~f0" /watch "%executable%" %max_seconds%^" >nul
    call "%executable%" -f "%beginning%%%A%extension%"
)

endlocal
exit /b 0


:watcher
set "executable=%~2"
if not defined executable exit /b 1
set "max_seconds=%~3"
if not defined max_seconds exit /b 2

rem Get the ProcessID aka pid.
set "pid="

for /f "tokens=2" %%A in (
    'tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %executable%" ^| find "%executable%"'
) do set "pid=%%~A"

if not defined pid exit /b 2

rem Let pid run for up to 15 seconds. Close pid if time elapsed.
for /l %%A in (1,1,%max_seconds%) do @(
    tasklist /nh /fi "pid eq %pid%" | find "%executable%" || exit /b 0
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak
)

taskkill /pid "%pid%"
exit /b 0
```

This code runs a 2nd process using `start` of the same script with an argument of `/watch`.

If calculate.exe runs longer than 15 seconds, then `taskkill` in the 2nd process will close the calculate.exe process.

The detection of calculate.exe in the `for /l` loop with `timeout`, uses the *process id* to check for the process as it is more unique than the *process name*.

This code may work correct only if no other instances of the process named calculate.exe are running at the same time.
The code uses the last *process id* of the running calculate.exe and any other running calculate.exe would mean that detection of the *process id* could be incorrect.

### Testing the watcher with echoed output

The labeled `:watcher` code is running as a child process in the same window.
If you want to see the stdout echoed from the child process then change this line:

> ```
> start "" /b cmd /s /d /c ^""%~f0" /watch "%executable%" %max_seconds%^" >nul
> ```

to

> ```
> start "" /b cmd /s /d /c ^""%~f0" /watch "%executable%" %max_seconds%^"
> ```

which has the trailing `>nul` removed. If you do this change, then you may want to silence `timeout` as it's stdout echoed is not of much use:

> ```
> timeout /t 1 /nobreak
> ```

to

> ```
> timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
> ```

which has the trailing `>nul` added to silence `timeout`.

Output of a test with changes made and `set "executable=calc.exe"` to run the *Windows Calculator*:

> ```
> calc.exe                      5600 Console                    1     13,896 K
> calc.exe                      5600 Console                    1     14,632 K
> calc.exe                      5600 Console                    1     14,656 K
> calc.exe                      5600 Console                    1     14,656 K
> calc.exe                      4800 Console                    1     13,860 K
> calc.exe                      4800 Console                    1     14,644 K
> calc.exe                      4800 Console                    1     14,644 K
> calc.exe                      4800 Console                    1     14,644 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     13,872 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,604 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> calc.exe                      5576 Console                    1     14,620 K
> SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 5576.
> ```

I closed the first two instances of `calc.exe` manually before the allowed 15 seconds.
The last instance of `calc.exe` timed out and was terminated by `taskkill`. The 2nd column of the `tasklist` output displays the *Process ID* of `5600`, `4800` and `5575`.

I used `>nul` in the initial code as displaying this output is a waste of console space in which you may want to see more important output.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks a lot for your explanations. I tried to copy/paste/adapt your code using `echo` commands to identify parts of the code. It never goes under `:watcher` even for idle files, only between `setlocal` and `endlocal`... Moreover without `call` for the `.exe` file, there is an `incorrect command` printed in the window but the calculation is **however** done correctly for normal files. As your approach seems to be be very well built, I will check how the `.exe` file is running when called.

Comment: `:watcher` code runs as a child process with stdout, which `echo` does by default, is redirected to `nul`. I updated the answer to show how to display stdout in `:watcher`. As for `call`, your description is broad as I do not know the difference between `.exe` file and normal file. Use of `call` for `.bat`, `.cmd` and `.exe` is useful to ensure execution of any of these file types in *batch-file* so I will add it into the answer.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you very much for your response. It works very well with a dummy .exe like calc.exe but not with mine. Indeed it is an in-house .exe tool so I fear that it keeps a certain authority level over a batch command. I consider that you did a very good job and I have to adapt it with my .exe file !